# kswapd0 takes my cpp program CPU usage to below 10%... How to overcome it?

Tags: c++, linux-kernel

I wrote a cpp program which reads several csv files and appends the data in a map >. The problem is that this data structure goes over 80% of my memory usage at some point, and then kswapd0 appears and takes my program CPU usage to belo 10%, which makes it extremely slow, given the nature of the program.

I do understand the nature of kswapd0, I know it wants to play around with disk and memory pagination, however I do still need my program to run!

Does anybody have a clue on how to overcome it?

The problem is not my program, I can ensure you that, because I separated the program in steps [basically grouping the files] and for some groups it doesn't happen, only for the real huge large groups take go over 85% of memory usage evoking kswapd0...

Comment: You ran out of memory and started paging. I'm not sure what you were expecting...

Comment: Nice time to understand `mmap`?

Comment: If you can't change the algorithm of the prog to use less ram, you simply need more ram. What else would you expect? Swapping needs much time and decrease overall system performance. Nothing what you can change per software or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

After certain memory usage kswapd0 starts. You can change the limits or disable it.

edit after comment:

you can check swapiness value with this code

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Mine was 60. It means after %60 of my memory use swap is kicking in. You can change this with a higher value or with "0" for disabling it.

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=90
```

I don't know your hardware but I'm using aws ec2 t instances. They don't have any space for swapping. So I've disabled it and my problem solved. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate, vote to close it as such. Don't post a link-only answer.

Comment: the other question is about amazon's small instance problem. Not same question exactly. But i will edit my answer anyway.